# Converting to a standard as.Date date-time then back again, without leading zeros

Tags: r, date, datetime, formatting

Is it possible to convert from R's default date format to a user-defined format ("m/d/yyyy" here) and avoid getting leading zeros in the resulting date?
In the example below I want to have `date_2` look just like `date_1`.  Is there a way to do this with `format` or another function (ideally in one line of code), or will I need to resort to `gsub` to find and remove the leading zeros in front of the month ("09") and day ("05") in `date_2`?

I looked in documentation on `DateTimeClasses`, `strptime`, `POSIXct`, and `format`, but didn't come across an answer.

```
date_1<-"9/5/2008"
date_num<-as.Date(date_1,"%m/%d/%Y")
> date_num
[1] "2008-09-05"

date_2<-format(date_num,"%m/%d/%Y")
date_2
[1] "09/05/2008"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go straight from `date_num` to your desired result, using the *chron* package.

```
paste(chron::month.day.year(date_num), collapse = "/")
# [1] "9/5/2008"
```

This also works nicely for multiple dates. The code is slightly different as we need `do.call()` here.

```
do.call(paste, c(chron::month.day.year(Sys.Date()-0:3), sep = "/"))
# [1] "10/9/2015" "10/8/2015" "10/7/2015" "10/6/2015"
```

Comment: Beautiful! The latter works well for me as I am looking to convert a data.frame column of dates all at once.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub('(?<=\\/)0|^0', '', date_2, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "9/5/2008"
```

Or another version is

```
gsub('0(?=[1-9]\\/)', '', date_2, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "9/5/2008"
```

We could also convert to `POSIXlt` class and then extract the components, `paste` it.

```
v1 <- as.POSIXlt(date_num)
paste(v1$mon+1L, v1$mday, v1$year+1900, sep='/')
#[1] "9/5/2008"
```

Comment: Or without the lookaround business `gsub("\\b0(\\d)\\b", "\\1", date_2)`